# How to include Header Files in different folder in C

Tags: c, gcc

My project structure is

```
    headers/
        include/
            myHeader.h
        myHeader.c
    testing/
        test.c
```

I tried compiling it with `gcc -c -I .../headers/myHeader.c testing.c -o test.exe`

but then I'll get an error that "include/myHeader.c" in myHeader.c is unknown and that the functions of myHeader.c are not known in test.c

It works when the project structure is

```
    include/
        myHeader.h
    myHeader.c
    test.c
```

But this structure is messy... how can I include a directory or even multiple directories with custom headers when compiling?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but is not `include` a directory? The two hyphens prefix makes it look like it is itself a file.

Comment: Headers should not have `.c` extension. The `-I` option is taking a directory, not specific files.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit the formatting of your project structure to make everything clear.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, there are two files named `myHeader`, one is `.c` and the other is `.h`, so confusing.

Comment: What's confusing is naming them `myHeader.*` and not something pertaining to their purpose. The `.h` file will contain declarations and perhaps macros. The `.c` file will include function and variable definitions. It's no more sensible than naming a variable `myVariable`, which gives no added value about its purpose at all.

Comment: Use `-I` to specify the directory where the headers are to be found, not a file name.  And if you specify `-I/somewhere/include`, then the header `/somewhere/include/header.h` should be found by `#include "header.h"` (or perhaps `#include <header.h>`, but most people reserve `<…>` for 'system headers' and use `"…"` for headers that are part of the project).  If you use `#include "include/header.h"`, then you need to specify `-I/somewhere` — the name in the `#include` line will be appended to the path in the `-I` option.

Comment: @Weather Vane. Yeah i know, i just wanted to mess around a bit and see how gcc and custom header-files would work :). I normally name them something like "networkingUtils.h"

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler so basically the command  "gcc -c -I .../headers/myHeader.c testing.c -o test.exe"?

Comment: No, not unless you are so perverse as to have a _directory_ called `myHeader.c` which contains header files that you want to include.  Most likely, you need `-I../headers`, but it does depend a bit on what you've written in your `#include` lines.  If you included just the header name, no path (`#include "header.h"`), then `-I../headers` should be OK (assuming that you're in the correct directory).  If you've written something else in the source code, then you have to modify what you specify on the command line.  And header file names should not end `.c` — the conventional ending is `.h`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler. Currently i do `#include "include/myHeader.h"` in my main file. So in order to compile i would need to change that to `"myHeader.h"` and then compile with `-I .../headers`  ?

Comment: Judging from your first file hierarchy diagram, yes — using `-I../headers` should work.  Using `-I.` would also work if `include` is a sub-directory of the directory where the `myHeader.c` source file lives (which is what your diagram suggests), but it raises the question of "what is a source file doing in a directory that claims to contain only headers?"

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler. My initinal idea is to make a folder where i can store all my custom header files in so i only need to copy and paste the folder from one project to another and just say "hey, include all that" and i am good to go.

I wanted to have the `.c` file in the same directory, because i only define the function headers in the .h and the functionallity in the .c file, this is how i learned it...

Comment: Maybe the directory name `headers` in the example is misleading.  It's feasible to have the source files (`.c` files) in one directory (`…/library`, for example) and to put the headers into a sub-directory (`…/library/include`), and work from there.  It is perhaps more common to have the source files in `…/library/source` and the headers in `…/library/include`.

Comment: Another fairly common organization is to have a central directory for headers (`…/project/include`) and the library source separately (`…/project/library`) and `…/project/source` for per-project source code (possibly with sub-directories for separate executables or modules).  The project then just adds an appropriate `-I` option to locate the (one) central header directory.